# How to update wxStatic Text in wxpython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am been trying to update wxStaticText without the existing text getting overlapped. I don't have a variable name for each StaticText which is my problem I guess. Full code:
http://pastebin.com/Y5k9qEa8

```
start=70
for i in newfp:
    #Gets info from website
    wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,str(newname),pos=(50,start))
    self.static = wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,price,pos=(250,start)) 
    start+=50
```

Then I have a refresh button that will run that same process again, but if the info changes, it will overlap.  I need to know how to make sure it does not overlap. Thanks in advance! Looking forward to the answers!

Comment: Generally when posting (epecially about ```wxpython```) its good to post a minimal working example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Sorry I am new to this!  Will update the post in a little bit!

Comment: Are you trying to create 70 wxStaticText widgets or trying to display new texts in the same one?

Comment: No I am using the start variable to make the text go down by 50 each time so the text does not overlap.

Comment: You can keep adding the texts to a single staticText using newline charater, or use a vertical sizer to add the staticTexts to. That way there will be no overlap

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but my main problem is when the user presses the refresh button that is there and the info from the website changed, the info overlaps and I don't want the user to see the old data.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: In that case try clearing the text of the staticText and then writing the new text to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to save a reference to it and use     `self.my_static_text.SetLabel("Some New 
Text!")`

ie

```
import wx
messages = ["Hello","World","Python"]
a = wx.App(redirect=False)
f = wx.Dialog(None,-1,"Changing Text!")
te = wx.StaticText(f,-1,"Changes!")
btn = wx.Button(f,-1,"Change The Text",pos=(10,25))
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,lambda evt:te.SetLabel(messages.pop(0)) or messages.append(te.GetLabel()))
f.ShowModal()
```

in your case you would keep a list

```
self.my_items,self.my_prices = [],[]
items = [("item1",50),("item2",75),("item3",88)]
for i,(itemName,itemPrice) in enumerate(items):
    self.my_items.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,itemName,pos=(50,start+i*50)))
    self.my_prices.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,itemPrice,pos=(250,start+i*50)))
```

here is a full example for your use case ... let it also serve as an example of what we want to see from you in terms of a runnable example in future questions

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,items):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,"Demo")
        self.start_y = 25
        self.my_items,self.my_prices = [],[]
        for i,(iName,iPrice) in enumerate(items):
            self.my_items.append(wx.StaticText(self,-1,iName,pos=(50,self.start_y+50*i)))
            self.my_prices.append(wx.StaticText(self,-1,str(iPrice),pos=(90,self.start_y+50*i)))
        btn = wx.Button(self,-1,"Next Items")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnNext)

    def OnNext(self,evt):
        for t1,t2 in zip(self.my_items,self.my_prices):
            t1.Destroy()
            t2.Destroy()
        self.my_items,self.my_prices = [],[]
        items = itemSets.pop(0)
        for i,(iName,iPrice) in enumerate(items):
            self.my_items.append(wx.StaticText(self,-1,iName,pos=(50,self.start_y+50*i)))
            self.my_prices.append(wx.StaticText(self,-1,str(iPrice),pos=(90,self.start_y+50*i)))
        itemSets.append(items)


itemSets = [
    [("item1",25),("item2",35),("item3",55)],
    [("item3",44),("item4",65),("item5",75)],
    [("item5",66),("item6",78),("item7",93)],
]
a = wx.App(redirect=None)
f = MyFrame([("ItemA",33),("ItemB",44),("ItemC",66)])
f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: So how would I do that if I don't know how many things the user is going input that it will have to loop through.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer many times! I am glad you answered with great detail as I am no expert, especially in wxPython.